# Multiple alarms in chrome extension?

Tags: chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I want to use chrome's alarm api for more than one event and both the event would notify at their respective time. Is their any way to separate the alarm tags so that i can trigger all the alarms differently.

Comment: Specify a `name` in chrome.alarms.create(), then check it in onAlarm listener.